# How to point local master to origin master with no committed files after repo creation?

Tags: git

I have just created my git repo in the git server (Bitbucket, GitHub, etc) and I want to link my local master with my origin master branch. **I do not want to add any of the current files I have in my project just yet**.

In my project folder I start by adding my remote:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@xxx/project.git
```

Then I want my local master branch to track my remote master branch:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master 
error: src refspec master does not match any.  
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xxx/project.git'
```

I also try:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist
```

Which is expected considering the master branch does not exist. Let's create it then:

```
$ git branch master
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
```

Seems that I can't create a branch named 'master'...

With that said, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a commit ready in order to be able to push to any branch. Considering you do not want to add any file in your first commit, simply perform an empty commit with the `--allow-empty` option:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial empty commit"
```

You can now successfully push your master branch:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 175 bytes | 175.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To xxx/project.git
* [new branch]      master -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

Git's trying to keep you safe from typos, to bypass the checks and set the configuration directly,

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "syncing stuff with the remote repository" : as long as your local repository is empty (e.g : no commit, no directory, no file), you don't need to take any action with the remote.

```
git  push --set-upstream origin master
```

will work just as well after you have actually created your first commit.

---

That being said, I also have taken the habit of creating a first empty commit as the "root commit" of my repos.

This allows for easier operations, e.g when I realise that I added too many files in my first actual commit.

e.g : "oops, remove `secret.conf`, add `"secret.conf"` in `.gitignore`", can now be done with a regular `rebase -i`